# SQL Server- How can I perform the same function as Excel index/match?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have the following code which works fine:

```
SELECT 
    CODE,
    TRADEDATE,
    SETTLE,
    SUBSTRING(EXPIRY, 1, 1) AS CONTRACT_CODE,
    SUBSTRING(EXPIRY, 2, 4) AS CONTRACT_YEAR 
FROM
    QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$
INNER JOIN 
    QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$ ON QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$.FULL_code = QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$.FULL_CODE
 WHERE 
    CODE IN ('CI', 'TC', 'PG', 'PW', 'NG', 'NL', 'PD', '8X', 'PH', 'PM', 'NJ', 'NX', 'TZ6', 'TR', 'NW', 'CL', 'CY', 'WJ')
    AND EXPIRY IN ('H2020')
ORDER BY 
    CODE ASC, TRADEDATE DESC, EXPIRY ASC
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I have another table called "contract_key" which contains two columns. One is "contract_code" and the other is "contract_month". What I need is to join the tables so I can see the contract_month, March, instead of the contract_code, H.

In Excel it would be

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(E2,B:B,0))
```

where column A is the month and column B is the code,cell E2 is the code H and the formula returns "3".

The desired output would look like this instead:

[image]

I'm using AR_MWCS$ to pull in the settle price. The table looks like this:

[image]

Table AR_MWCF$ looks like this:

[image]

I'm using substring to split EXPIRY into "H" and "2020"

Table CONTRACT_KEY looks like this:

[image]

So I need to join the CONTRACT_CODE from table CONTRACT_KEY and the substring CONTRACT_CODE created from table AR_MWCF$ to find the contract month then combine the contract month with the contract year as a date.

I was able to get my desired output by modifying the code to:

```
SELECT 
     CODE
    ,TRADEDATE
    ,SETTLE
    ,CONCAT(CONTRACT_MONTH,'-','01','-',CONTRACT_YEAR) AS EXPIRATION

FROM
     QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$

INNER JOIN 
    QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$
 ON QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$.FULL_code = QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$.FULL_CODE

INNER JOIN
    QUANDL.DBO.CONTRACT_KEY
ON QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$.CONTRACT_CODE = QUANDL.DBO.CONTRACT_KEY.CONTRACT_CODE


WHERE 
    CODE IN ('CI','TC','PG','PW','NG','NL','PD','8X','PH','PM','NJ','NX','TZ6','TR','NW','CL','CY','WJ')

ORDER BY 
    CODE ASC, TRADEDATE DESC, EXPIRY ASC
```

Which returns the following:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you just need to join the two tables and display the column from the other table. Sample data and desired output would go a long way here.

Comment: Okay but how do I do that?

Comment: As I said previously, sample data and desired output would go a long way here. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     CODE,
     TRADEDATE,
     SETTLE,
     contract_key.contract_month AS Expiration
FROM QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$
INNER JOIN QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$ 
           ON QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$.FULL_code = QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$.FULL_CODE    
INNER JOIN contract_key ON contract_key.contract_code = QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$.FULL_code
```

*We do not know which, if any, of your original tables contains a joinable "CODE" field.  I used MWCS$.FULL_Code as the joinable table and field.  Use MWCS$ or MWCF$ and FULL_Code or PARTIAL_code or CD as the case may be for the Excel field you seek.*

```
 WHERE 
    CODE IN ('CI', 'TC', 'PG', 'PW', 'NG', 'NL', 'PD', '8X', 'PH', 'PM', 'NJ', 'NX', 'TZ6', 'TR', 'NW', 'CL', 'CY', 'WJ')
    AND EXPIRY IN ('H2020')
ORDER BY 
    CODE ASC, TRADEDATE DESC, EXPIRY ASC
```

Comment: Be sure to mark correct answers.  I noticed after my post you solved your issue all on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for what I needed:

```
SELECT 
     CODE
    ,TRADEDATE
    ,SETTLE
    ,CONCAT(CONTRACT_MONTH,'-','01','-',CONTRACT_YEAR) AS EXPIRATION

FROM
     QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$

INNER JOIN 
    QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$
 ON QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCS$.FULL_code = QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$.FULL_CODE

INNER JOIN
    QUANDL.DBO.CONTRACT_KEY
ON QUANDL.DBO.AR_MWCF$.CONTRACT_CODE = QUANDL.DBO.CONTRACT_KEY.CONTRACT_CODE


WHERE 
    CODE IN ('CI','TC','PG','PW','NG','NL','PD','8X','PH','PM','NJ','NX','TZ6','TR','NW','CL','CY','WJ')

ORDER BY 
    CODE ASC, TRADEDATE DESC, EXPIRY ASC
```